# Add marker to a strip

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to add a marker to a **strip** in the VSE? I don't want to add the marker to the timeline with <kbd>m</kbd>, but to the selected strip, e.g. to mark possible cut positions to choose from. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, video-editor strips don't have their own markers.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this is to cut the strip soft. Place the green time cursor where you might want to cut, then hit <kbd>K</kbd>. By selecting both ends of the cut, you can move the cut around, since both strips keep their original length under the hood.

Until you delete or move one of the strips, the cut is not noticable. and you can always restor one of them to full length.

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is really great suggestion - in some cases it can be OK, but it will interfere with animation, effects and modifier stack.

Comment: It has been designed not to be a great answer. But if at least one blenderhead gets a useful idea out of it, it's worth mentioning it.

Comment: fine - but in that case the answer should note drawbacks with the proposed solution.

Comment: Oh, please don't get me wrong. I really do appreciate the second half of your first comment. And whenever I'm aware of drawbacks, I note them myself.