# VSE - Move Markers and Strips Simultaneously

Tags: video-sequence-editor, marker

I love the markers feature in VSE but they don't stay in sync with strips as I edit them down (cut portions out). Is there a way to have a marker link directly with a moment in a strip so they are always in sync? A similar question was asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3045) in 2013.

Alternatively, is there a way to move strips and markers simultaneously? My workaround is whenever I move a strip I pay attention to how many frames I move it. But markers move in seconds so I have to divide by the framerate to move them the same amount (e.g. 300 frames / 30fps = 10 seconds). Very tedious. I also like to press "]" to select all assets after the playhead but it doesn't select markers.

Comment: i think an add-on might do this or you write a python script for it. AFAIK a marker is just fixed to a frame - not to a strip.

Comment: Good suggestion but I haven't found any addons that have this functionality. The VSEQF add-on has some useful features and it even lets you make tags that can mark a moment in a strip but it's not quite enough. I really should learn Python...

Answer (score 2):

[image]Selecting markers and clips, you can type -> G (to move) -> Number#frames

This will move both simultaneously by frame count.